# Cast Receiver in android devices

Tags: android, chromecast, miracast

While searching for chrome cast and miracast i found their is only web implementation for receiver side. But i found some app in google play store which is working exactly what i need.

- [CastReceiver](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.softmedia.receiver.castapp&hl=en&rdid=com.softmedia.receiver.castapp)
- [AirScreen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ionitech.airscreen&hl=en)

How these apps works then? Is their anyone know how can i do same thing as they did?

Comment: This is not an appropriate question for stack overflow.

Comment: See https://github.com/intel/wds for an open source  miracast implementation (not ready for production use, it's a working proof of concept)